# Next.js Fetching Data Inside Nested Child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Please consider my circumstance:  In [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/), I have built a component that is intended to be a child component that fetches data on its own (without any parent component) and now I have [come to find this is not allowed](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/2068#issuecomment-304177295) by the authors of next.js.  However, they mention the `async-reactor` library as a workaround:

> May be you can try something like async-reactor

But I tried using `async-reactor` and was unable to render a fetch inside a nested child component in Next.js still.  Here's what I tried:

```
// my child component 
import React from 'react';
import {asyncReactor} from 'async-reactor';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';

function Loader() {

  return (
<div>
    <h2>Loading ...</h2>
</div>
  );
}

async function AsyncPosts() {
  const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  const posts = await data.json();

  return (
<div>
    <ul>
      {posts.map((x) => <li key={x.id}>{x.title}</li>)}
    </ul>
</div>
  );
}

export default asyncReactor(AsyncPosts, Loader);
```

I expected this to work but it doesn't render anything except the word "Div" (which isn't even supposed to render "Div").

Is there a way to fetch within a child component in Next.js?  Nothing I have tried so far worked but I find it hard to believe this is truly not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Arunoda wrote:

> We don't have plans to add support for calling **getInitialProps** in nested components.

The emphasis is on `getInitialProps`, you can make an ajax request inside any component, but know the benefits / drawback of it.

This ajax request will be implemented inside `componentDidMount` / `useEffect` hook which are **not called** at server-side.

One of the benefits can be lazy loading data, you don't need the entire page's data up front, that means less data => smaller network request.

One drawback can be that this section won't be passed to next's SSR mechanism, therefore won't be easily SEOed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  So, is it correct to say I must bring in the data at the highest level component and then pass it to all the children as props, making attempts to bring in the data through a child component futile?  Or, is it true that I could trigger an ajax request from inside a child component using ```componentDidMount``` / ```useEffect``` to bring in data (even if it's partial data)?  Just needed clarification as your answer gave me hope for this and I have an idea how to potentially solve it.

Comment: It is a matter of what you need, as a rule of thumb, fetch important (above the fold / SEO) data in getInitialProps, pass it to children (can be done using context, so no need for prop drilling), use fetch in nested component for less important data.